# Pushing objects to an array in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

'both' is my object that should hold 2 arrays: eng, fr.

These arrays each, hold multiple objects.

How do I push every value from frDisplayData to fr:[] in my 'both' object:

```
const displayData = [];
var both = {eng:displayData, fr:[]};
displayData.forEach(function (item) {
  // You must call .then on the promise to capture the results regardless of the promise state (resolved or still pending)
  translateText(item.explanation, 'fr').then(function(result) {
    frExplanation = result;
    frTitle = translateText(item.title, 'fr').then(function(result) {
      frTitle = result;
      frDisplayData = {
          date: item.date,
          explanation: frExplanation,
          hdurl: item.hdurl,
          media_type: item.media_type,
          service_version: item.service_version,
          tite: frTitle,
          url: item.url
        }
      console.log(frDisplayData);
    })
  });
})
```

Any simplified solution to this would also help.

Currently, console.log(frDisplayData); gives me the following:

```
 {
  date: '2022-03-26',
  explanation: "xyz",        
  hdurl: 'xyz.jpg',
  media_type: 'image',
  service_version: 'v1',
  tite: 'Pluton la nuit',
  url: 'xyz.jpg'
}
{
  date: '2022-03-27',
  explanation: "abc",        
  hdurl: 'abc.jpg',
  media_type: 'image',
  service_version: 'v1',
  tite: 'Titan Seas reflète la lumière du soleil',
  url: 'abc.jpg'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have an array `displayData` containing data in English and you want translate **title** and **explanation** properties in each element to French and store in `fr` variable.

You can use `forEach` loop on display data and `async`, `await` on promise to get much cleaner code.

```
const displayData = [
  {
    title: "title1",
    explanation: "exp1",
    // other props
  },
];

const fr = [];

// use async callback func in foreach
displayData.forEach(async (each) => {
  // create a copy of eng element
  const eachfr = { ...each };
  
  // use await operators to for translation
  // translate required properties to french
  eachfr.title = await translate(each.title, 'fr');
  eachfr.explanation = await translate(each.explanation, 'fr');
  
  fr.push(eachfr);
});

const both = { eng: displayData, fr: fr };
```

Answer (score 0):

"fr" is a key within the "both" object. All you would have to do is add both.fr.push(frDisplayData) within your "forEach" loop.

```js
const displayData = [];
var both = {eng:displayData, fr:[]};
displayData.forEach(function (item) {
  // You must call .then on the promise to capture the results regardless of the promise state (resolved or still pending)
  translateText(item.explanation, 'fr').then(function(result) {
    frExplanation = result;
    frTitle = translateText(item.title, 'fr').then(function(result) {
      frTitle = result;
      frDisplayData = {
          date: item.date,
          explanation: frExplanation,
          hdurl: item.hdurl,
          media_type: item.media_type,
          service_version: item.service_version,
          tite: frTitle,
          url: item.url
        }
      console.log(frDisplayData);
      both.fr.push(frDisplayData);
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: Nope, that did not work. I'm getting the same output.